# Icinga2 check_load plugin thresholds

Tags: plugins, ubuntu-16.04, icinga2

I've recently installed Icinga2 on a bunch of Ubuntu LXC containers. I have a master node where you can log into icingaweb to check status.

However the load thresholds seem low and I cannot see how our even where you can adjust the parameters. May I ask for someone to point me in the right direction? Is this done on the master or the remote nodes? What's the file and where does it sit in the file structure?

I installed Icinga2 on Ubuntu 16.04 server from the Icinga2 PPA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a service definition for load in master:

```
apply Service "load" {
    import "generic-service"
    check_command = "load"
    vars.load_wload1 = 5
    vars.load_wload5 = 4
    vars.load_wload15 = 3
    vars.load_cload1 = 10
    vars.load_cload5 = 6
    vars.load_cload15 = 4
    command_endpoint = host.address
    assign where host.name == "monitored client"
}
```

More info [here](https://docs.icinga.com/icinga2/latest/doc/module/icinga2/chapter/plugin-check-commands#plugin-check-command-load)

Comment: Thank you, but the check_load plugin already exists and is running by default, I just want to change the threshold. What's the filepath for that?

Comment: `icinga2 object list --type Service --name "load"`

Comment: Cool, thanks. May I ask what the numbers mean? i.e. after the equals sign? Are they minutes, seconds? something else?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks :-)

Comment: eekfonky can you share what you figured out.. where did you end up adjusting the thresholds for the check_load plugin on the master??